# Getting source code from apk file for third party packages

Tags: android, decompiler

how to decompile third party packages?? I have tried the decompilation of my own apk's..those are working fine... Can some one please tell me is there any way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this steps:

1)Use apktool on your application:

```
apktool d -s -r APPNAME.apk
```

You will get structure of project like:

```
│   AndroidManifest.xml
│   apktool.yml
│   classes.dex(!)
│   resources.arsc
│
├───assets
├───lib
└───res
```

Or near it. 
2) Use d2j-dex2jar tool:

```
d2j-dex2jar classes.dex
```

3) Open file in JD-GUI and read :)

Comment: I might also add, that there is modern alternative to this APKTool->dex2jar->JD-GUI route!

Just try open-source APK and DEX decompiler called Jadx: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jadx/files/ 
It has also online version here: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk